# PHP - using update with variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php to update a mysql DB within a function. I am able to echo my variable names and was able to return the variables on the php page. This proves to me that my variables are working correctly.

Now when I use the update command, my DB does not respond. Yes, I have connected to the DB and it all works.

This is what I am using to update:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name`
            SET `int_field` = '$int_value'
            WHERE `username` = $username");
```

Comment: After query, you should check the result, from the error, you will find the wrong part easily. For you case, you missed the quotes for `$username`

Comment: Swap the string-delimeters from the int to string perhaps?..  mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET int_field = $int_value WHERE username = '$username'");

Comment: @enhzflep mysql automatically converts it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for `$username` should be wrap with `single quotes`.

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE table_name 
                 SET int_field = '$int_value' 
               WHERE username = '$username'");
```

SideNote: your code is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please read the article below to know how to secure your code,

[**Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks, that had worked using quotes around $username. And thanks for the sql injection link. I am using a sanitize function on all field variables as well.

Comment: @SlapShot you are welcome :D and Welcome to StackOverFlow Community!

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote all of your input to the query. This prevents SQL injection, but also simple syntax errors that would occur if your user innocently inputs a special character that would break your query.

```
mysql_query('UPDATE table_name '.
            'SET int_field = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($int_value).'" '.
            'WHERE username = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($username).'"');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct STRUCTURE of how to update with a variable in php

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET password='". $NPass ."' WHERE custID='$num'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
         mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name`
         SET `int_field` = '$int_value'
        WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that the SET value doesn't need single quotes and that the WHERE clause does ...

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET int_field=$int_value
WHERE username='$username'");
```

.. seemed to work for me.